# Stack/Ensemble Estimators Using SKlearn Pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, ensemble-learning

While learning to use Pipelines and GridSearchCV, i made an attempt to ensemble a Random Forest Regressor with a Support Vector Regressor. Individually GridSearchCV put both at about 90 % score, were I was quite stuck. But putting the SVR before the random forest in the pipeline, it jumped to 92%.

I couldn't find any example of this, so I assume it's not very useful, incorrect, or that there's a better of way doing it. Would appreciate any guidance.

I created a quick example using SKLearn's Boston Housing set with Lasso and Random forest. Combining gave an increase in "mean_test_score" from around 62 % to 65 %. The relevant snippet is below, full notebook is at: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Blebg/ce279345456dc706d2deddcfab49a984

```
class Lasso_t(Lasso): #Give Lasso a transform function

    def transform(self, x):
        return super(Lasso_t, self).predict(x).reshape(-1, 1)


#The pipe creates a Lasso regression prediction that Random Forest gets as a variable
pipe = Pipeline(steps = [
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('union', FeatureUnion([('reg', Lasso_t(alpha = 0.2)),
                            ('keep_X', FunctionTransformer(lambda x : x))])),
    ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100))]) 

params = dict(
    rf__min_samples_leaf = [1,5,10],
    rf__max_features = ['log2','sqrt'])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=params, cv = 5)
grid_search.fit(X,y)
pd.DataFrame(grid_search.cv_results_).sort_values(by = 'rank_test_score').head(3)
```

Comment: So what do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to combine my two regressesors in hope of improving regression score. I wonder what the best way of doing that is, and if the way I did it works. I ended up adding transform functions to estimators here, which does feel a bit wrong.

Comment: You may want to look into "Stacking". Predicting with one or more estimators and using the output as input to final estimator. https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/classifier/StackingClassifier/

Comment: Thank you! That seem like a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You might looking for [`sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html) which can combine two regression models by taking their mean.

Here is an example to get you started:

```py
from sklearn.datasets        import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble        import RandomForestRegressor, VotingRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline        import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing   import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm             import SVR

# Make fake data     
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1_000, n_features=20, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=42)

pipe = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),
                 ('vr', VotingRegressor([('svr', SVR()), ('rfr', RandomForestRegressor())]))
                ])

search_space = [{'vr__rfr__min_samples_leaf': [1, 5, 10]}]

gs_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                     param_grid=search_space,
                     n_jobs=-1)

gs_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
gs_cv.predict(X_test)
```